# Exactly one rebalancing for a kafka consumer group while dynamically adding a new member and removing an exiting member

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a scenario where  I need to dynamically/programatically remove an exiting (low performance) kafka consumer from a certain group, and simulatenously add another (high performance) kafka consumer to that group.

I am able to achieve this dynamically but at the cost of two rebalancing operations. (even though the commands to add/remove the consumers are performed in parallel by two different threads).

Is it possible to achieve this removal/addition using exactly once rebalancing? any configuration/trick that could help for exactly one rebalancing?

Answer (score 0):

Any change to the group will cause a rebalance. The removal and addition are considered distinct events for the rebalance protocol, even if ran simultaneously